# Highlight and comment parts of questions for comments

Tags: feature-request, comments

Often I find my comments on questions are specific to a piece of text in the question, such as "What does 'foo the bar in the baz' mean?". The OP will then clarify and now my comment is pointless or refers to text that doesn't exist and so I have to zap it.

Google docs has a feature where you can select text and add a note. If I could do this on a SO question it could:

- save me having to retype 'foo the bar in the baz' - I would just highlight that text, right-click and type "what does this mean?"
- locate the comment popup at the relevant text, which would have some kind of indicator that there was an inline comment there
- have a "resolved" button to quickly remove the comment.

Obviously it would only be useful for ephemeral comments, and the risk is getting a question smothered in useless inline comments. On the plus side, it removes ephemeral comments from the comments under the question, where they clutter up true comments on the broad nature of the question which should have a longer life.

Probably quite a bit of coding though, but I reckon no more than is currently being spent writing some stupid holiday season party hat code... :)

Comment: `and so I have to zap it`.... that's actually how the system is supposed to work.  If the comment is no longer relevant, delete it.

Comment: doesn't detract from the idea of having comments next to the text they are commenting on - or do you stick all your code comments at the end of each subroutine?

Comment: I would find such a feature highly distracting. A couple friends of mine and I collaborate via Google docs, and we use chat to, like comments on SO, quote the passage we have an issue with and explain why. If there were inline comments in the text I was reading, I'd have to keep stopping to look at the inline comments, possibly forget what I had already been through depending on what I'm thinking concerning the inline comment, and even possibly start re-reading. On top of that, how would the usefulness outweigh the "smothering" risk you mention in your question?

Comment: When I collaborate with google docs, notes are exactly the right thing to markup possible edits, suggestions, etc. But -3 says ppl don't agree its the way to do things here. Fairy snuff.

Comment: @Spacedman The right way to markup possible edits here is the "edit" button at the bottom of the question. :) If the OP hates your edit, they can roll it back. If you don't feel comfortable with that, then comments are absolutely the way to go, and can be deleted or flagged as obsolete after the edit is handled.

Comment: While I'm thinking of it, it's worth noting that a Google collaboration with a limited number of people is _far_ easier to manage those comments on than a website with a couple million users, like what SO has.